# How to align two boxes?

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, templates, thesis

I found the following template for my master thesis and this is the preview for the cover:

- professor (adviser)
- co-professor (2nd adviser)
- candidate

[image]

The problem is that I would the box "Candidato" aligned with "Relatore" but I don't know how to modify the following section (there are two different boxes, BoxRelatori and BoxCandidati, defined with the tabular command, the first aligned with "l" and the second with "r"):

```
     \def\BoxRelatori{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \hbox{\ifclassica\else\large\fi
              \textbf{\protect\@nomerelatore}}\\[.6ex]
        \hbox{\large\textrm{\protect\@principaladviser}}%
        \ifx\@secondadviser\empty \else
           \ifclassica
              \ifx\@thirdadviser\empty
                 \ifx\@secondadviser\empty\else
                       \\[1.5ex]\textbf{\Correlatore:}%
                 \fi
              \else
                 \\[1.5ex]\textbf{\Correlatori:}%
              \fi
           \fi
           \\[.6ex]\hbox{{\large\textrm{\protect\@secondadviser}}}%
        \fi
        \ifx\@thirdadviser\empty \else
           \\[.6ex] \hbox{{\large\textrm{\protect\@thirdadviser}}}%
        \fi
        \end{tabular}%
     }%
  \def\BoxCandidati{%
     \begin{tabular}[t]{r}%
        \hbox{\unless\ifclassica\large\fi
           \textbf{\protect\@nomecandidato}}\\[.6ex]
           \hbox{\large\textrm{\protect\@author}}%
           \ifx\@secondauthor\empty
           \else
              \\\hbox{\large\textrm{\protect\@secondauthor}}%
           \fi
           \ifx\@thirdauthor\empty
           \else
              \\\hbox{\large\textrm{\protect\@thirdauthor}}%
           \fi
     \end{tabular}%
```

line 341-376: see the file here https://pastebin.com/xHYTr0Th

main .tex file here: https://pastebin.com/rraW1jaj

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a code which produces a result likes in your image?

Comment: Of course, but there are several files. If it helps, this is the link where I downloaded it
https://nl.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/italian-thesis-template-(toptesi)

Comment: Just a small file, and the macro/class file(s).

Comment: Linked two paste text

Comment: Tip for the future: Do not hide name parts using an external program, just replace the names. How about Francesco Frankenstein, or Alessandro Antman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\textbf{Relatore:}\\
Ch.mo Prof.\,Ing.\,Francesco da Assisi

\medskip
\textbf{Correlatore:}\\
Ing.\ Umberto Eco
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\textbf{Candidato:}\\
Alessandro da Macedonia\\
Persepolis
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary to construct an elaborate template. Two `minipage` environments, the first with ragged-right contents, the second with ragged-left contents, should suffice.

It wasn't clear to me if the minipages should be stacked horizontally or vertically. The following screenshot shows solutions for both possibilities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\obeylines
\raggedright
\textbf{Relatore:}
Ch.mo Prof.\ Ing.\ Francesco da Assisi

\medskip
\textbf{Correlatore:}
Ing.\ Umberto Eco
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\obeylines
\textbf{Candidato:}
Alessandro da Macedonia
Persepolis
\end{minipage}

\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\obeylines
\raggedright
\textbf{Relatore:}
Ch.mo Prof.\ Ing.\ Francesco da Assisi

\medskip
\textbf{Correlatore:}
Ing.\ Umberto Eco
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\obeylines
\textbf{Candidato:}
Alessandro da Macedonia
Babylon
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```